# Import collection to non-local address with Mongo restore

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mlab, database

I'm trying to copy over a collection from an instance of a mongoDB on my local machine to a collection hosted by mongoLabs.

I'm able to dump the collection into a `dump` directory, but when I try to import with the command below I get a: `No such file or directory: "/dump/my_db/my_coll.bson"` error. This is the command I use:

```
mongorestore -h ds047057.mongolab.com:47057 -d main_db -c main_coll -u xxxx -p xxxx /dump/my_db/my_coll.bson
```

I still get the same error if I use the full pathname.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to point `mongorestore` at the directory containing your db rather than the file containing the specific collection you're targeting. So:

```
mongorestore -h ds047057.mongolab.com:47057 -d main_db -c main_coll -u xxxx -p xxxx /dump/my_db
```

Comment: thanks I was able to rectify it by removing the 'forward slash' before 'dump': `mongorestore -h ds047057.mongolab.com:47057 -d main_db -c main_coll -u xxxx -p xxxx dump/my_db/my_coll.bson `. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Thanks jared!

The --directoryperdb can not work when authorized below.

```
mongorestore -u xxx_production -p -h 127.0.0.1 --directoryperdb rongyoudao_production_mongodb
```

While the -d works below.

```
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1:27017 -d xxx_production -u xxx -p  /root/backups/2014-06-19/xxx_production_mongodb/xxx_production
```